# How to ignoring empty string during deserialization by GSON

Tags: java

I would like to remove empty string by using toJson from GSON.
Example object:

```
public class ExampleObject {
    String defaultEmpty = "";
    String example;

    public ExampleObject() {
        this.example = "foo";
    }
```

and after

using

```
new Gson().toJson(new ExampleObject());
```

I am receiving

```
  "defaultEmpty " : "",
   "position" : "foo"
```

Is there any way to not including empty string during deserialization? I know GSON is ignoring `null`, but sometimes I have an empty string in my object and I have to ignore it.

Comment: If you don't want the behavior of the default `toJson`, then write your own `toJson`. I'm not sure exactly what the question is meant to be here.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I would like to skip empty json in the result of the string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800319/how-do-i-treat-empty-strings-as-null-objects-with-gson

Comment: I've read that one, but this is not what I've expected. I can't manipulate model - anyway, thanks!

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example.

```
static class ExampleObjectSerializer implements JsonSerializer<ExampleObject> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ExampleObject src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty("example", src.example);
        if(src.defaultEmpty != null && !src.defaultEmpty.equals("")) {
            object.addProperty("defaultEmpty", src.defaultEmpty);
        }
        return object;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ExampleObject.class, new ExampleObjectSerializer()).create();
    ExampleObject exampleObject = new ExampleObject();
    String result = gson.toJson(exampleObject);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```